Swapping palettes using Shader Graph in Unity
What I am trying to do is: Swap between palettes for one character. There is a character imported from .aseprite (via unity aseprite importer) and two other .asperite files that are palette definitions.
I have managed to do what I want, but partially. I can switch between palettes but colors are not correct.
Here is my shader graph look like:

Also here are link for files I am using: Google drive link
Thanks in advance for help.

Looks like you are only reading the R-value of the MainTex-texture. This probably tints all the colours of your texture that contain som red, resulting in som wierd end results.
What happens if you feed it RGB instead?
If you want to change specific areas of the sprite (the hairband for instance) you might want to have a separate mask for those parts.

I tried your suggestion, but didn't work (Rsults changed but still not correct). Still I am not sore if I did it correctly. @azelito
